# C - opening and reading from a file

Tags: c

Compilable Code
    `

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE * openFile(int argc, char *argv[]);
int readMonth(FILE *fin);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

int month, choice;
int * temps;
FILE * fin = NULL;

fin = openFile(argc, argv);

month = readMonth(fin);

}  


FILE * openFile(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int test;
    FILE * fin = NULL;
    fin = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &test);
    if(fin==NULL){
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);}
    return fin;
}

int readMonth(FILE *fin)
{
    int month=0;
    int n = fscanf(fin, "%d", &month);
    if(n!=1)
    {printf("error reading month from file\n");
    exit(1);}
    printf("%d\n", month);
    return month;
}`
```

I am trying to read data out of a text file and I'm getting weird results.

I call fileOpen from main to return the file pointer, this is my function:

```
FILE * fileOpen(int argc, char *argv[])

{

    FILE* fin = NULL;
    fin = fopen(*argv, argc);
    return fin;
}
```

then calling readMonth to read the first line of the file, it does not print the correct 
int.

```
int readMonth(FILE *fin)
{

    int month=0;
    fscanf(fin, "%d", &month);
    printf("%d", month);
    return month;
}
```

I am not sure if the error is with the file opening or the reading the file.

Comment: Debug. Debug. Debugger!!!!

Comment: And read the manual page or `fopen` for a start - i.e. http://linux.die.net/man/3/fopen

Comment: Check the return value of fopen for 0. If fopen fails it returns 0 ( NULL).

Comment: Better, but you never print out 'test' and that fscanf that scans 'test' should be after the fin == NULL test.

Comment: fopen(argv[2], "r"); will open the 2rd argument on the command line. argv[0] is the program name, argv[1] is the first argument, and argv[2] is the second argument. If your command line is "program a b" Your program will open and read from "b".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions.  1. Check the return value of fopen

```
FILE *fileOpen(int argc, char *argv[] {
    FILE* fin = NULL;
    fin = fopen(*argv, "r");
    if(fin == NULL) { // this block is new
        perror("fopen");
        exit(1); 
    }
    return fin;
}
```

Note: If the `argc` and `argv` are from main, then `*argv` is `argv[0]` which is the name of the program. You probably want `argv[1]`. And you should check that `argc >= 2` in `main`.

2: Check the return value of fscanf:

```
int readMonth(FILE *fin)
{

    int month=0;
    int n = fscanf(fin, "%d", &month);
    if(n != 1) { // this block is new
        printf("error reading month from file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("%d", month);
    return month;
}
```

With these two changes your code should function properly.

Comment: I added both of these error checks and the the program is not exiting. It is printing "12" when .txt file has a single 2 on the first line.

Comment: Post your *compilable* code ( the whole thing ) and the file you are reading from. What you describe does not make sense given the data we have.

Comment: Also, one more thing I noticed, the second argument to fopen should be "r". See the code above.

Comment: I am using "r" for testing it. But is it supposed to be a command line argument passed in

Comment: The "r" means read. Probably not to be passed in from the command line. The name of the file to read, the first argument to fopen, should come from the command line. Probably argv[1], not argv[2].

Comment: Good luck. I gotta go...

Answer (score 0):

You can read the first line of the file using `fgets` in function `readmonth`

```
char buffer[1024];
char *l ;
if((l=fgets(buffer,sizeof(buffer),fin))!=NULL)
  printf("%d",atoi(l));
```

Also , you can check if the file opening failed using

```
   if(fin == NULL) 
    printf("failed");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
FILE * file = fopen(data, "r");
if(file==NULL){
    printf("404 File Not Found\n");
    exit(-1);
}
while(1)
{
    char line[100];

    int res = fscanf(file, "%s", line);
    if(res == EOF)
        break;

    fscanf(file, "%s", &var);

 // handle the var
 }
```